# Android studio 3.3 On Mac, Logcat No optional window was found

Tags: android

Android Studio 3.3.2
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5314842, built on February 16, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.3

Logcat no available selection window was found

(https://github.com/whsgzcy/READMYSELF/blob/master/images/t.png)

Comment: you should add the android studio tag

Comment: I change my version and ok, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I change a version:
Android Studio 3.2
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5014246, built on September 18, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.3

ok,